# Why is this Javascript not being compatible with Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, syntax-error, identifier

Every time I try to view my webpage in Google Chrome I get this:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:tickercontent.txt?bustcache=1306951376114. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
ajaxticker.js:63Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

And nothing displays on the page at all.

```
ajax_ticker.prototype.getXMLfile=function(){
    this.ajaxobj=createAjaxObj() //recreate Ajax object (IE seems to require it)
    if (this.ajaxobj){
        var instanceOfTicker=this
        var url=this.xmlfile+"?bustcache="+new Date().getTime()
        this.ajaxobj.onreadystatechange=function(){instanceOfTicker.initialize()}
        this.ajaxobj.open('GET', url, true)
        this.ajaxobj.send(null)
    }
}
```

Line 63 would be "this.ajaxobj.send(null)"

Comment: `Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP` - Ergo no local system file access and no HTTPS access.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is by-design. Possible solutions are discussed in [chromium issue 47416](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47416).

The only current workaround is to launch chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files